# Spring data - check if User "can" be inserted?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data

in spring boot, spring data, and ms sql,
how can I handle insertion of user, if it contains values in unique fields, which are already in database ?

Is there something like check, if user CAN be inserted ?

As right now, I have following code:
User repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public boolean existsByName(String name);
}
```

User service:

```
public void registerNewUser(RegisterUserDto toRegisterDto) throws UserAlreadyExistsException {
         //check ALL unique fields ?
        if(userRepository.existsByName(toRegisterDto.getName())) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException();
        }
        User entity = convertToEntity(toRegisterDto);

        User saved = userRepository.save(entity);
    }
```

So, my questions:
1) How, in easiest way, can be checked, if user CAN be inserted, following all database constraints - like unique values ?
2)If spring data throws exception while inserting duplicated user, how it can be properly handled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to update already existed data, your code is the best code. and here is simpler code. 
Insert first, then DBMS raises ConstraintViolationException or something. Catch exception and handle it.

```
try {
   User saved = userRepository.save(entity);
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) { // detailed Exception is different by DBMS and JPA implemetation
    throw new UserAlreadyExistsException();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#dao .Spring data re-throws any implementation dependant exception as DataAccessException. BUT, I want to check SIMPLY what happened, and re-throw it as my inner application exception and based on it return some String message in handler. Is it possible ?

Comment: Returned String message must be concrete, like "Username already taken", "Mail already taken"; and if some error occurs, then "Error saving user, try again."

Comment: It's depend on implementation. So you test unique violation case and see what is exact throwed Exception.
And Yes. It is possible. throw new YourCustomException("your message");

Comment: Okay, I checked https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html; and ConstraintViolationException returns Set of ConstraintViolation, which has some methods to work with further, Marked as answer, although I think that this is nowhere clean code.